# Disabling Partner Community User Visibility

Tags: contact, partner-portal

I want to prevent community users that belong to same partner account from seeing their peers. For example, there is an account ABC and there are 2 Community Users from this account as primary and the respective users have the same Role of ABC Partner User.

There are also contacts related to this account who are Users in the community that are shared with each other with reason as "Associated Portal User or Role". Setting the Community User Visibility to false did not disable this behavior.

Let me know if I have missed any critical step. The sharing setting on Contact is Private in our Org. Please help!

So what does "Portal User Visibility" checkbox on the Sharing Setting page do?

Comment: Just to make certain here, this is a Partner **Portal** and not a community? Also, all the Partner Users involved here have the same Roles and Profiles? You talk of contacts and Users. In a Partner Portal, Contacts become Portal Users. Contacts that aren't Portal Users are still contacts and Portal Users may have access to them, so the distinction is important. To clarify your question, are you asking how to prevent these two Portal Users from seeing one another in the Partner Portal?

Comment: Hi crmprogdev. This is Partner Community with user license of Partner Community Login. Partner Users have role of "ABC Partner User", where ABC is the organization name. So it varies based on the primary organization on the contact. Both the contacts in the above example are activated as users and have the same role of ABC Partner User. Yes is the anser to your last question.

Comment: I've edited your original post to reflect what I think you conveyed in your reply to my questions. You can update your question at any time by clicking on the "edit" link at the bottom left of your post. Portals still exist and operate slightly differently, so it's important not to use the term interchangeably with Community.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than I can put into comments, so I'm going to compose it as an answer to your question.

From what you've told us, it sounds as though the users with "Associated Portal User" Role are from accounts that are owned by Users from accounts with the Role of "ABC Partner User". From that, I'm going to infer that they're both from the ABC Partner Account. It also sounds from what you've said, particularly since you don't want them to see each other, that the other two Users who have roles of "Associated Portal Users" are from two different accounts that are owned by the ABC Partner Account. Would that be correct?

Going on that assumption, let me say first that permissions are controlled by profiles along with permission sets, the latter being something that's often applied to groups. Roles will have NO effect on visibility. In a Partner Community, Users are just that "Users". Anyone who isn't a Partner Community User is a Contact. If they're a member of the Partner Community, then they're a Partner Community User who will have both a Role and a Profile within the Community (if a Customer Community, they won't a Role, only a Profile). See [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/) for more on the basics of how communities work and setting them up.

Ideally, in a Partner Community, any Users from accounts owned by a Partner would be added to the Community in a heirarchy. So, if you have the ABC Partner Account and they own BCA Plumbing along with AAA Refrigeration, those two accounts would be set up as child accounts of the ABC Partner Account. If done that way, when those users were created, they could be owned by the ABC Partner Account, the sharing on those USERS could be set to private, and they wouldn't see one another. The only Users who'd have permission to see them would be those in Roles above them at the ABC Partner Account.

I hope this is all making sense to you. You may also find more on this subject if you look in the [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/). There's an External Sharing model that can be configured for Users, Accounts, Contacts, etc in addition to an internal sharing model. In this type of situation, you'll likely want to impliment both models. There's also more information on this in Salesforce Help.

Feel free to comment under your original post if you have more questions or need clarification (you don't have the reputation to comment under this one, but can always coment under your own). You can also edit your original post with more details about the sharing model you're using.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please let me know what does "Portal User Visibility" checkbox on the Sharing Setting page do?

Comment: Deselect the Portal User Visibility checkbox to allow users to be seen by only themselves and their superiors. Or select the checkbox to let portal users be seen by all other portal users within the same account. See [Controlling Who Community or Portal Users Can See](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_external_user_settings.htm&language=en_US) for more on the subject. If this post leads you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.

Comment: That is what I understood too! But it is not working as expected after I deselect the check box. I will let you know if  find something in this regard. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Because this is a Partner Community where Roles exist, I suggest you focus on the external sharing model for Users. If it's not set to Private, I'm not entirely certain the above setting will have the same effect. I believe it is intended primarily for use with Customer Community Users where Users do not have Roles. Your Roles could be impacting visibility since I don't believe there's a "Report to" setting in Communities like there is internally. (I haven't done enough with partner communities to know).